# Doubt in geometry of nilpotent elements.

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, nonstandard-analysis

I was reading commutative algebra from Miles Reid where I got stuck in the geometry of nilpotent element on page 29.

> The geometric picture of nilpotents is in the spirit of a nonrigorous 
>   introduction to calculus, where one may talk about a "number e so 
>   small that $e^2 = 0$", and use this to calculate the derivative f'(x) of a 
>   polynomial by the formula f(x + e) 
>   = f(x) + ef'(x). This is of course 
>   nonsense in the context of an element of the real field, but is perfectly 
>   sensible and useful in algebra. Thus the element $Y \in k[X, Y]/(Y^2)$ is 
>   pictured as the function on the X-axis with values in $k[e]/(e^2 
> = 0) $ which 
>   remembers the $Y$ derivative $(df/dY)(x, 0) $ of $f(X, Y) \in k[X, Y] $ at each 
>   point $(x,0)$. Higher order nilpotents can be used to give an algebraic 
>   treatment of Taylor expansions of polynomials up to any order.

What does this paragraph even mean? How is the geometry of nilpotent element related to calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the (average) slope of a function over the interval $[x,x+\Delta x]$ is given by 
$$
m = \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x},
$$
and the derivative of a function is defined by 
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}.
$$
The reason we need to  take a limit is that taking the slope of a function between points $x$ and $x + \Delta x$ doesn't make sense if $\Delta x = 0$; plugging in $\Delta x = 0$ forces us to divide by zero.

The (non-rigorous version of the) idea of $e$ is to play the role of an "infinitely small element", so that we can calculate the derivative as a "slope".  That is, $e$ is "so small that" the average slope over $[x,x+e]$ is $f'(x)$, i.e. exactly equal to the slope at $x$. In terms of the formulas above, this amounts to saying that
$$
f'(x) = \frac{f(x + e) - f(x)}{e} \implies f(x+e) = f(x) + f'(x) \cdot e.
$$

Comment: So e is not equal to zero but some power of e is 0 which allows us to find the slope?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea behind it. The way that "powers of $e$" come into it becomes clearer if you think in terms of Taylor series: we have
$$
f(x+e) = f(x) + f'(x)e + \frac 12 f''(x) e^2 + \cdots = f(x) + f'(x) e + 0.
$$